# If I have php in database can I use that?

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

If I have php within my database can I use that. Specifically I have`<?php echo $email; ?>` with a column called content. On a protected page called user I call on the content column and spit out a page. Similar to a blog would within a while mysqli. When I look into my database though I see the function is actually the full `<?php echo $email; ?>` rather than the actual variable that was posted with a form.

Edit:

Also I'm looking within firebug to see what shows up for value within the form and it is indeed the full echo statement. The echo statement is pulled from the database as part of a stored form. Is this not good practice? If so how can this be done? Am I missing something??

Further info is that I am using mysqli escape string to input the data..

I've got a script that echos out the content for the page. In this case the content from the database is a form which includes a hidden field for email. This way I can tell whos posting to the database so that we can establish a connection.

Within the original page are active variables that are included on this particular page. I'm including in the form from the database a field like so:

```
<input type="hidden" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
```

Normally the echo would work, but I'm not sure why its not. That is why I ask if the fact that that input field is coming from the database has any bearing on it not echoing based on the variables already located within the page?

Further example for explanation:

```
<?php
include_once "includes/db_conx.php";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM course ORDER BY id DESC";
$sql_page = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_page)){

 $email = $row["email"]; 
}
?>
```

Thats the email on the actual user.php page.....

Now the user.php also has an area for content..

```
<?php
include_once "includes/db_conx.php";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$sql_page = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_page)){

 $content = $row["content"]; 
}
?>
```

We'll say that the content looks like this...

```
    <form>
     <input type="hidden" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
//    
</form>
```

This also outputs on user.php
notice that user.php does have $email....how are you saying to approach this? How else can I echo this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP eval() code in between <?php ?> from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072434/php-eval-code-in-between-php-from-database)

Comment: Not really considered best practice.  There are less-complex ways of doing what you want to do, like templating. It's the eval() function you're (hopefully no longer) looking for though!

Comment: I don't think I'm using eval()...I'll re explain above..hang on one second @NeilNeyman

Comment: I guess I'm saying you don't want to store lines of code in the DB to pull and execute (which is what you would do with eval() ). Even if you're stripping off the code just to get the variable contents it seems something is gone horribly wrong with the design.

Comment: What is stored, is a form. That is outputed through a variable called content. The $content loads on a page called user.php. The $content variable is showing <?php echo email; ?> instead of user@user.com. To find the user.user.com variable the <?php echo should get it from the user.php page. Does this make sense? You'er saying this is bad practice, right? Can you recommend a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Ok I'm getting a better understanding of what you're saying now.  Do you require() the user.php page in your script? Or is this all being called from user.php.  Do you know what exactly is in the DB column/row?

Comment: Also just a wild guess but is your actual form outputting in an html file or a php file?  Some file type where your server knows to parse php tags.

Comment: The script that outputs the content is on the user.php page.

EDIT: Yes the database shows the full <?php echo email; ?> rather than the email itself. It isn't echoing on the page, within the value="" section.

Comment: The script is outputting in a php file.

Comment: the script for the actual form runs off page, but the problem is the variables aren't echo according to firebug.....in past if I echo a variable from a single page it works fine, but the issue is the echos are coming from the database and they aren't firing off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments I'd say a quick answer is to check the linked article in my first comment.  Yes the problem is your Form Output code is likely expecting data in a variable and not code.  You need to eval() the variable in order to actually execute the code contained within.  However this is not best practice.

A better solution would be to just store the contents of $email in the DB and just send that to your form

It's the difference between:

```
$x = '<php? echo $hello ?>';

$outstr= "<input type='hidden' value=' $x ' >";
//no this wont work unless you use eval($x)
```

EDIT:

Based on your explanation above with content, you may just need a way to ignore everything between the  tags in content and replace it with the actual content?  I'm assuming you can't change the db design...

Two quick& dirty & perhaps unsafe thing you can try is:

```
include("data:,$content");
//or
eval('?>'.$content.'<?');
```

Or you can replace with regex:

```
$phpTagPattern = "#<\?.*?(echo)\s+(\$\w+);.*?(\?>|$)#s";  //just searching specifically
                          //for <?php echo $varname; ?>  to replace with $varname;
$replacePattern = "$2"; // this may need some cleaning/debugging here. It's late...
$newContent = preg_replace($phpTagPattern,$replacePattern,$content);
```

Then you're still going to have to parse_str to get the variable contents anyway...somewhat safer than executing code perhaps.

```
echo parse_str($newContent); //should get you to actual contents of $email variable
```

This all might be more easily achieved with the tokenizer extension:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokenizer.examples.php
You'd be searching for T_OPEN_TAG and T_CLOSE_TAG.

For a high-level Better Way To Do This(TM) kind of explanation, it would make more sense to simply store your actual data in the database, and put the content into a templating engine like smarty.  Then you create the shell of the form and just pass variables to it where needed.  Keep data separate from logic, and output/formatting markup separate still.

Comment: The email is stored and used on the same page(user.php) else where...just not within the form itself. If I echo manually it goes great, but if echo within the pulled content it doesnt. Are we still on the same page?

Comment: Yeah if you have the email just echo it.  You don't want to echo the pulled content and eval is a bit wonky.  Because you are just echoing php code.  The code won't execute unless you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: how do I echo it if its within the form? I'm totally confused with what you mean...you say to use it which I'm willing to do, but thats what I thought I was doing...the only thing I'm grabbing from the content column from the db is the form with that input and variable...You say to use it, but thats what I thought I was doing.

Comment: You say it's stored and used elsewhere on the page correctly.  How is it done there?  I assume that means you already have a variable that contains what you want ?  Edit-- see addendum above.

Comment: I've just included more to the above original post.

Comment: I did a workaround and I believe the solution here is to output the variable upon cnoditions...I think I finally figured that out from what you're saying. Is this correct?

Comment: I will stay away from eval as suggested...since its only one page and necessary upon conditions I instead went a different route involving the on page variable you suggested...thanks so much for your help Neil. 

Also that was not the answer to the issue Neil as suggested in my post. Thanks!