# Is it possible to run php code from a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database with multiple questions.
Some questions contain php variables.
When I try to echo the mysql data the variables don't work.

I'f tried eval, but most people say it is not safe and it doesn't work for me.

Database.php

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vragen ORDER BY RAND()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$vragen = print_r($row[vraag],true);
```

mysql data

```sql
$player1[$rnd1]." take 2 drinks"
```

game.php

```php
require "database.php";
    echo $vragen;  // string with hardcoded variables
```

I expect to get the variables working in php.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing these questions with the variables in them

Comment: In short, no. Longer answer is that you're essentially trying to build a templating engine. Take a look here: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/847/top-7-best-open-source-php-template-engines

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using the `eval` keyword. For example (using the variables in your example):

```
# This would interpret everything stored in this variable as PHP code.
eval($vragen);
```

Keep in mind that the `eval` keyword does not return a value, so if your goal is to `echo` the output you don't need `echo` when using `eval`. For example:

```
eval($vragen);
```

will output the contents of `$vragen` directly into the output stream (browser), but

```
$return_value = eval($vragen);
```

will only check if `eval` was able to run or not. Any `return;` or `return false` will end the `eval` code.

Finally, it may be worth noting that in terms of accessing variables from the PHP script that `eval` is run in, per the PHP manual:

> The code will be executed in the scope of the code calling eval(). Thus any variables defined or changed in the eval() call will remain visible after it terminates.

You can find other examples about the `eval` keyword used in the context of PHP stored in MySQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072434/php-eval-code-in-between-php-from-database).

However, as correctly pointed out by the above commenters, this is highly discouraged for many reasons outside of the scope of your question (is it possible). However, there is an interesting discussion on why you shouldn't do this [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/146537/how-to-securely-run-php-from-a-mysql-database), if you're interested.

For more information on the `eval` keyword the PHP manual page is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom [native functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-native-function.html) in MySQL by compiling C code into the server and you can call external processes in C programs so I guess the answer is *yes*. That answers your question but doesn't solve your problem.

You're using PHP to retrieve those strings anyway. You can simply manipulate them *after* fetching them:

```
$input = '{player1} buys 2 drinks for {player2}.';
$variables = [
    '{player1}' => 'Jim',
    '{player2}' => 'Joe',
];
$output = strtr($input, $variables);
```